# How can I create an extension for a VStack with properties in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

I would like to apply a list of properties to a VStack instead of a shape. The following code is applying my list of properties to a shape through innerN function that is defined in a Shape extension:

```
ZStack {
  Color.mph
  let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
  //let shape = Circle() //it works with any shapes
            
  shape
     .innerN(Color.mph)
     .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
}

extension Shape {
    public func innerN<S:ShapeStyle>
    (_ fillContent: S) -> some View
    {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fillContent)
                .overlay(
                    self
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 4)
                        .blur(radius: 4)
                        .offset(x: 2, y: 2)
                        .mask(self.fill(LinearGradient(Color.black, Color.clear)))
                )
                .overlay(
                    self
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 8)
                        .blur(radius: 4)
                        .offset(x: -2, y: -2)
                        .mask(self.fill(LinearGradient(Color.clear, Color.black)))
                )
        }
    }
    
}
```

How can I modify my extension so I could something like? :

```
VStack(spacing: 20){//...}
 .padding()
 .cornerRadius(25)
 //.innerN(color) //with the shape of that VStack
```

Comment: What happens if you use ```extension View``` instead of Shape? It will work for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add after the VStack:

```
.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25) //the shape you want
    .innerN(Color.mph)
)
```